# Non-English Windows directory name in url link

Tags: php, windows, directory, filenames

I have a php file that searches a computer's windows directory. If I have a directory which contains a non-English character like "Önder Şoğlopıpk" it returns null.
My Php file is so:

```
$port = $_GET["port"];//Here is computer's port
$path = trim($_GET["path"]);//Here is the path which does not work
$path = str_replace(" ","+",$path);
$path = urlencode($path);
$suffix = $_GET["suffix"];//Here is suffix which I am searching
if($_GET){ 
$url='http://mylink.com?host=localhost&port='.$port.'&showerrorinxml=yes&link=proc_list?find_files___path='.$path.'___suffix='.$suffix.'';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

If there is a non-English character in path variable like "Ş Ğ ı ş ğ I" it returns null to me. If it is English there is no problem. I can search what I want.
I am urlencoding it but it did not work.
My url seems like for a directory named "Seçpa Yazılım Login" is:

```
http://mylink.com?host=localhost&port=44833&showerrorinxml=yes&link=proc_list?find_files___path=D%3A%2FSe%C3%A7pa%2BYaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m%2BLogin%2F___suffix=.css
```

And it seems on the browser so that:

```
http://mylink.com?host=localhost&port=44833&showerrorinxml=yes&link=proc_list?find_files___path=D%3A%2FSeçpa%2BYazılım%2BLogin%2F___suffix=.css
```

Anyone has an idea about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `urldecode` the input after retrieving it:

```
$path = trim( urldecode( $_GET['path'] ) );
```

**UPDATE:** OK, read your question more carefully. To me it seems as if you are encoding the URL twice. The first time implicit by sending it from your browser through an HTTP request and the second time at `$path = urlencode( $path );`